# How to Obfuscate credentials in a .conf file in Linux?

Tags: linux, awk, centos, configuration-files, credentials

I am trying to provide credentials to an app and it needs them in a ".conf" file. At most i came up and tried below line.

```
password = awk '/^password/{print $0}' /root/.creds| awk '{split($0,a,"="); a[2]}'
```

This line didn't work, i am trying to replace the user name and password using some kind of awk command, unfortunately its a "conf" file.

Edit: Adding more information; this is the text line directly from the conf file , i assumed it will auto execute and present creds to the application rather than "awk" command, which was wrong.

Comment: FYI `awk '/^password/{print $0}' /root/.creds| awk '{split($0,a,"="); a[2]}'` can be written as just `awk -F'=' '/^password/{print $2}' /root/.creds`. [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you further.

Comment: @EdMorton I suspect that *is* the sample the OP has tried. I think the OP has put that text in their conf file and thought it would be autoexecuted or something.

Comment: I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding of the concept of a conf file here. It's not executable. It's just a file that the command / daemon will read on startup (and possibly other times as well). Unless that command / daemon says that the value is a command to run, it doesn't get executed. Instead, limit access to the credentials by setting user, group and other permissions properly so that no one else can read the contents.

Comment: @Tanktalus right, that's the code they executed but what I'm asking to see is what text they're executing it ON and what the tool output should be. We also need to know in what way it `didin't work`.